# How much solar wind (mass) hits Mercury's north pole?

Tags: solar-wind, mercury, magnetosphere

I understand the solar wind impacts and sputters the surface of Mercury's north pole due to it's magnetic field deflecting it around the planet.

Comment: I don't think any space probes have been able to measure the **quantity** of solar wind hitting the north pole. Why do you want to know ?

Comment: Since the solar wind is denser nearer to the sun and even denser as it is pushed around the planet and into poles, I was wondering if someone wanted to collect a significant portion at the north pole how much there'd be to collect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a proper answer, but:

The measurements by [MESSENGER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESSENGER) spacecraft has shown that Mercury's magnetic field is tilted:

[image]
[(source)](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/charts/mercurys-magnetic-field.html)

[Here is a 2017 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05060.pdf) that summarizes recent discoveries.

quote:

> MESSENGER magnetometer data show that Mercury’s magnetic field is not only exceptionally
>   weak but also has a unique geometry. The internal field resembles an axial dipole **that
>   is offset to the North by 20%** of the planetary radius.

So, *same as on Earth amd most other planets*, Mercury's magnetic poles do not coincide with rotation poles.

If your question is about **the origin of ice deposits at Mercury permanently-shadowed craters**, I've found a couple of links:

https://www.zmescience.com/space/astronomy-space/origins-water-ice-mercury/
https://www.seeker.com/mercury-water-ice-comet-asteroid-mission-mystery-2248445071.html

As I remember, solar wind was considered too as a source of hydrogen for water ice, [especially for the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_water#Possible_water_cycle). But looks like the meteor/comet bombardment is evaluared as most probable source of the ice on Mercury currently.